# Tracking mouse movement (shape) on screen - Python

Tags: python, tracking, mousemove

I am trying to track the movement of the mouse on the screen while pressing right-click and saving the movement into a 2D shape (either .dwg or other) into a new file. What is the best way to approach this?

I have looked into PyMouse and briefly into PyGame but so far. But, because I still have a limited understanding of coding, I don't understand how to actually use them and create a running application.

I have tried these simple examples for basic function of PyMouse (https://github.com/pepijndevos/PyMouse/wiki/Documentation) but don't know how to get from here to tracking a user mouse movement.

I'd appreciate any kind of tips for this!

Answer (score 1):

For the mouse tracking event, you can use the `if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:` statement.

The full code below:

```
import pygame,sys,numpy
pygame.init()
display = (1500, 900)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(display)
pygame.display.set_caption("Shape")

draw = False
size = (15,15)
run = True
shape = []

while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 3: #Detect right-click; left-click is 1
            draw = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 3: #Detect release right-click
            draw = False
            #Here to save the file of 2d shape
            shape = []



    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    #Draw the shape
    if draw == True:
        shape.append(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
        for i in shape:
            screen.fill((255,255,255), (i, size))

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

I think there is a way to save list as a 2d file. Check out https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52705/how-to-write-shapely-geometries-to-shapefiles and it might help you. Just add the saving-file process after the `#Here to save the file of 2d shape` comment.

I will be working on the saving-file part, but this is the best I can get for now.

Comment: If you want to continue working on the 2d shape after mouse release, you can comment out the ```shape = []``` and ```draw = False``` part and add a keydown event after finishes and then save the file. If you are using the link above, make sure to pip3 install the shapely and the fiona module.